# Threads in OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I need to achieve the C# threads effect in C++ OpenMP..

```
Thread t=new Thread( func1 );
t.Start(); // Do something
// Do something else
```

Notice that neither the parent or the child waits to be joined..

Can I do this in C++ OpenMP ??

Thanks,

Comment: As I understand it, the whole point of openMP is that the compiler generates the code to spawn multiple threads for you.

Comment: What if I need to start a thread and do not wait for it to finish..?

Comment: I don't think OpenMP is what you're looking for here.  Any standard threading library will be able do do what you're doing.  OpenMP is for automatically parallelizing sections of code that can be parallelized.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is a higher level threading library than C# threads and is often used to almost automatically add some threading to serial applications.  You may be able to achieve something similar to what you want by using the `#pragma omp parallel` directive which will automatically run the code within the directive block in multiple threads.  You could then call the function in this parallel section.

The strength of OpenMP is that it is simple to add threading to existing code with a few directives.  However, I have found it easier to use a lower level threading library if I want to do anything complicated (or easy for that matter).

If you want something with a similar interface to C# threads, take a look at the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) library.  With this, you can do what you want in almost the same syntax:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

//creates the thread object and starts the thread, returns immediately
boost::thread th(func1);

//...
//do something else
//...
```

Comment: That means that what I am asking is impossible in OpenMP?

Comment: If you don't want the thread to join back into the main thread, I think this would be difficult in OpenMP.  Most of the OpenMP constructs are blocks that completely contain all parallel operation and things are assumed to be serial outside the block (by joining at the end of the block).  This makes things easier to understand and not mess up, but limits what you can do.  This is not to say that something like what you want can't be done with OpneMP, I just think it would get pretty clunky.  However, I haven't used OpenMP in a long time so there may be an easy way I don't know.

Comment: The closest thing is `#pragma omp parallel sections` followed by a `#pragma omp parallel section` directive for each block of code to run in a different thread.  However, this joins the threads at the end automatically.